# How to pass value from one form to another form's dynamically created control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Suppose I have two forms i.e `Form1` and `Form2`. Form1 contains dynamically created `DataGridView` control and `Form2` contains two `Textbox` controls (`Textbox1` and `Textbox2)` and a `Button` control.

When I `DoubleClick` on the `DataGridView`'s cell it will open `Form2` and  the data from current selected cell passes to `Form2`'s `Textbox1`

Here is the code:

I Added a handlear to my dynamically created DatagridView like this:

```
    AddHandler dg.CellMouseDoubleClick, AddressOf dg_DataGridEdit
```

```
    Private Sub dg_DataGridEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
                Dim dgView As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        Form2.TextBox1.Text = dgView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()
                Form2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

When i click on the button from Form2, the value of current selected cell will change like TextBox2 from Form2 has. But the problem is i can't use the code from button1 from From2 like

```
    Form1.dgView.CurrentCell.Value = TextBox2.Text
```

How can i pass value from textbox2 to current selected cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. 
At first i have created a public variable called

```
    Public UpdateData As String = ""
```

Then change the code-

```
    Private Sub dg_DataGridEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)

                Dim dgView As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
                Form2.TextBox1.Text = dgView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()
                Form2.ShowDialog()
                dgView.CurrentCell.Value =UpdateData
                UpdateData=""
    End Sub
```

In form2

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        form1.UpdateData = TextBox2.Text
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your DataGridView, store a reference to it:

```
private _myDgv as DataGridView

Sub Form_load
    _myDgv = New dataGridView
    Me.Controls.Add(_myDgv)
    'etc.
End Sub
```

Then Add a ReadOnly Property to get a reference to it from elsewhere:

```
Public ReadOnly Property DynamicDgv As DataGridView
    Get
        Return _myDgv
    End Get
End Property
```

Then you can do this in Form2:

```
Form1.DynamicDgv.CurrentCell.Value = TextBox2.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the default instances.  Here is an example that uses a textbox on each form:

form1

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f As New Form2(TextBox1F1) 'pass ref to form2
        f.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

form2

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim txtbox As TextBox

    Public Sub New(tb As TextBox)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        txtbox = tb 'get ref from calling form
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        TextBox1F2.Text = txtbox.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1F2.TextChanged
        txtbox.Text = TextBox1F2.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any changes to the textbox on form2 will be reflected in the textbox on form1.

Comment: The issue is nothing to do with default form instances (and indeed you don't explain why you recommend against these)

Comment: If you use the default instance of the form, then any changes to that form are changing it for the lifetime of the app.  Say that he form has 10 fields as textboxes and the user fills them in.  The next time the form is shown those textboxes will have the same data instead of being blank.  I wouldn't use the default instance for many other reasons, more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Here is a good example of the 'right' way:  http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html

Answer (score 0):

You may pass the datagridview of `Form1` to `Form2` through `Form2`'s constructor. Then you'll be able to access the `CurrentCell` of the datagridview of `Form1` as like your last code snippet.

You can have a constructor in `Form2` which'll take the datagridview as argument.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private dgView As New DataGridView
    Public Sub New(ByRef _dgView As DataGridView)
        dgView = _dgView
    End Sub

End Class
```

When you create the instance of `Form2` in `Form1`, pass the dgView to Form2 like:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Form2 As New Form2(dgView)

End Class
```

Now when you click the button in `Form2`, just set the `CurrentCell` of the dgView in the button event handler like:

```
dgView.CurrentCell.Value = TextBox2.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copying to clipboard as a workaround so you don't have to pass the text from one method to the next

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(...)

System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(...)
```

Comment: I think this can be a solution. But after click on Button form2 hide but how to get the text from clipboard and set to the current cell?

Comment: Once the data is in the clipboard then retrieve it like `Form1.dgView.CurrentCell.Value = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text)`

Comment: A poor solution IMO - there is no need to use the clipboard for this

Comment: I can't take your solution as answer. But your technique helped me. If  user store some valuable data in clipboard for other purpose this technique will remove this data. So i can't use this.