# Updating the text on a dynamically generated control In VB

Tags: vb.net

I have a dynamically generated TabControl, and am trying to update a Combobox in the TabPage. The function that updates the Combobox is called of a click event.

I've tried to follow some guides regarding manipulating dynamically generated controls by storing the dynamically generated controls as properties on the class: [How to pass value from one form to another form's dynamically created control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065830/how-to-pass-value-from-one-form-to-another-forms-dynamically-created-control?rq=1)

The controls are generated dynamically as such:

```
    Public Class Form1
           Public Sub loadForm()
           Dim ctp As New CustomTabPage("Tab number" & i, ErrorList(i), myList, New Object)
           Me.myTabControl.TabPages.Add(ctp)
            ...
           End Sub
        End Class

        Public Class CustomTabPage
            Inherits TabPage
            Private m_testSelect As ComboBox
            ...
            Public Property testSelect() As ComboBox
               Get
                   testSelect = m_testSelect
               End Get
               Set(ByVal mytestSelect As ComboBox)
                   m_testSelect = mytestSelect
               End Set
            End Property

            Public Sub newTab()
            m_testSelect = New ComboBox    
            With m_testSelect
                    .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(locX + labelSize, locY)
            End With
            Me.Controls.Add(m_testSelect)

            Dim ccb As New CustomCheckBox()
            Me.Controls.Add(m_testSelect)
            End Sub
            Public Sub UpdateCBOs(ByVal i As Integer)
                If i = 1 Then
                    testSelect.Text = "Test1"
                ElseIf i = 0 Then
                    testSelect.Text = "Test2"
                End If
                ... 
            End Sub
        End Class

        Public Class CustomCheckBox
               Inherits CheckBox
               Public Sub Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.CheckedChanged
                    Dim ctp = CType(Form1.myTabControl.SelectedTab, CustomTabPage)
                    ctp.UpdateCBOs(i)
                End Sub
         End Class
```

Currently while debugging through I stop on the line after line 
        errorBy.Text = "Test1"

When I mouse over errorBy.Text, and see that errorBy.Text ="" and indeed after the click event finishes, I see on the form that the combobox is not updated.

Comment: This code doesn't run and I am unable to make it work. Can you add the missing elements such that it does reproduce the problem you are describing, please?

Comment: With regards to the comment by @JayV, please see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).  All new members should spend some time perusing the Help documentation but few ever do and there's often some back and forth before their questions can be answered as a result.